# how to use LEFT JOIN in mysql?

Tags: mysql

sorry for this question

sorry for this question 
sorry for this question

Comment: the author changed the full contents of the original post

Answer (score 1):

This subquery:

```
(select b.country_name from mydatabase.country_codes as a left join mydatabase.countries as b 
on a.country_code = b.country_code 
where b.language_code = 'EN') as c
```

don't give us the required `c.country_code` , so add it to this query

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only the country_name, but not the country_code in your subquery, that's why you can't use it later